# Return always same color by index from javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a button to generate a chart pie with chartjs.

Based on filters inserted, i get result like ( Name | Value%):

```
Service_1 |  10
Service_2 |  15
Service_3 |  75
```

Sometime some result doesn't appear, for example:

```
Service_1 |  20
Service_3 |  20
Service_4 |  60
...
```

**I'd like to use always same color for each service.**

For example

```
Service_1 always #ccc
Service_2 always #fff
Service_3 always #000
etc...
```

Now i'm using this usefull solution: using http://google.github.io/palette.js/

```
//json_labels are for Name
//json_results are for Value%

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
        labels: json_labels,
        datasets: [{
            label: '',
            data: json_results,
            backgroundColor: palette('rainbow', json_results.length).map(function(hex) {
    return "#" + hex;
            })
         }],
      ...
```

But map doesn't work like I need cause if Service_2 doesn't appear in results, Service_3 get #fff instead #000 and so on...

I'd like to correct this part:

```
backgroundColor: palette('rainbow', json_results.length).map(function(hex) {
        return "#" + hex;
})
```

I've max of 100 Service so I can create an array of fixed 100 colors for example.
But i've no idea to map correct indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a result object is like `{ service: 'Service_1', value: 10 }`

Try this:

```
palette('rainbow', 100) // <--- create a palette with every color
    .reduce((c, n, i) =>  //    then pick only colors that match a service name using the palette color index
        [...c, ...(json_results.find(row => r.service == `Service_${i+1}`) ? [`#${n}`] : [])], [])
```

```js
var palette = Array(100).fill().map((_, i) => `${i}`.padStart(6, '0'));

json_results = [{
  service: 'Service_12', value: 9
  }, {
  service: 'Service_54', value: 10
}]

var mapped = palette
  .reduce((c, n, i) => 
    [...c, ...(json_results.find(r => r.service == `Service_${i+1}`) ? [`#${n}`] : [])], [])

console.log(mapped)
```

Comment: Hi i get error palette is not a function. can you post you code in jsfiddle? thanks

Comment: You need to apply the reduce function on your code... my snippet is just an axample

Comment: Ah ok. I've never used reduce and i don't know how it works. I'll search for docs